# can't do cd using docker running on Ubuntu container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run, docker-multi-stage-build

When I'm trying to install packages in requirements to the dir '/home/site/wwwroot' I'm getting the following error

```
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/site/wwwroot
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /home/site/wwwroot &&     pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Here's is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:2.0

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot



FROM ubuntu
# ...
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and My requirements.txt is

```
    azure-functions
pyodbc
pandas
numpy
azure-eventhub
```

how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in your last stage no exists the location `/home/site/wwwroot`.

You must copy this folder from a previus stage  somethig like this

```
 COPY --from=previus_stage /home/site/wwwroot /home/site/wwwroot
```

another thing, your env variables should be like this.

```
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot
ENV AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```